# Keeping post_date same as the pending post_date on privately publishing the post

Tags: date, wp-update-post

I'm saving my CPT in [`private` status](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/v0.3.3/includes/ns-set-environment.php#L355-L377). So the transition would be from `pending` to `private`. Thing is, when the post was first submitted and is pending there's a date of that submission on the `post_date` field in db. But when the post got published, the date updated with the current date.

I want to keep the original date of the submission of the post even the post privately published later.

So I did something like below:

```
function mycpt_keep_pending_date_on_publishing( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if( 'mycpt' === $post->post_type && 'pending' === $old_status && 'private' === $new_status ) :
        $pending_datetime = get_post_field( 'post_date', $post->ID, 'raw' );

        // Update the post  
        $modified_post = array(  
            'ID'            => $post->ID,  
            'post_date'     => $pending_datetime,
            'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $pending_datetime )
        );  

        // Update the post into the database  
        wp_update_post( $modified_post );

    endif;
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'mycpt_keep_pending_date_on_publishing' );
```

But it's not working. What can be the reason?

Comment: Just FYI, there is [`{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/old_status_to_new_status/) hook. If I were to make a wild guess, I would think that the post_date gets updated [on publish](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3605) before it actually gets set to private.

Comment: Tried `pending_to_publish` and `pending_to_private`. Tried updating the post from front end with my code and from admin end with core code. No luck. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Howdy_McGee is on the right track in his comment: by the time [transition_post_status](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status) is fired, the post has already been updated (i.e., written to the db).

What you need to do is hook into [wp_insert_post_data](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/), **instead of** `transition_post_status`, as follows:

```
add_filter ('wp_insert_post_data', 'mycpt_keep_pending_date_on_publishing', 10, 2) ;

function
mycpt_keep_pending_date_on_publishing ($data, $postarr)
{
    if ($data['post_type'] != 'mycpt') {
        return ($data) ;
        }

    // this check amounts to the same thing as transition_post_status(private, pending)
    if ('private' != $data['post_status'] || 'pending' != $postarr['original_post_status']) {
        return ($data) ;
        }

    $pending_datetime = get_post_field ('post_date', $data['ID'], 'raw') ;

    $data['post_date'] = $pending_datetime ;
    $data['post_date_gmt'] = get_gmt_from_date ($pending_datetime) ;

    return ($data) ;
}
```

**Note:** I used the same function name as you did, but the body of that function is different.

Comment: I would suggest to hook above filter callback inside the `wp_insert_post_data` hook, but remove it again during the transitioning hook to make sure it only runs once. There are plenty of example here on this site for this.

Comment: @kaiser in case it wasn't clear, I'm suggesting the above code _instead of_, not  _in addition to_, hooking into `transition_post_status`.  I edited my answer to make that a little clearer.

Comment: I know. And I suggested to _remove_ the callback right inside the transition hook, so it does not interfere with any later code. There might be other things like plugins, that modify post data as well and one should be sure that you only do your task once. Take a look [at this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98294/385) for an example.

Comment: Added your code, it's **working fine** if the post is updated from the admin panel. But if it's updated from the front end, even changes like [this](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/commit/8a6e61f30c8eff0f1f01166f3bc0fc63e9319940#diff-fc28a31c4f3bf484dbf9f03d3e7a038aR780) isn't working. Could you please shed some light there?

Comment: I just did a quick scan of of your code on github.  Adding `'original_post_status' => 'pending'` to [line 771 of includes/ns-functions.php](https://github.com/nanodesigns/nanosupport/blob/master/includes/ns-functions.php) should do the trick.  That is passed to `wp_update_post()` when a post is updated on the backend and is used in the code in my answer to mimic `transition_post_status`.

Comment: There is no such thing as `original_post_status` in WordPress. Your code seems to check if the post is transitioning from pending, but it's not. Your code always gets triggered, no matter what transition status it comes and goes to.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, here's a small plugin that makes sure the code is only executed once. In case the data is reset by a plugin running later, try using `PHP_INT_MAX -1` as priority (not for publicly distributed plugins). In this case, you will have to set the same value for `remove_filter()`, else the callback will not get removed.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (WPSE) Static post date
 * Description: Keep the post date as the original date for posts published as private
 */
namespace WPSE;

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', '\WPSE\save', 10, 2 );
function save( $post, $raw ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $post['post_status'], [ 'private', 'pending', ] ) ) {
        return $post;
    }
    if ( 'your_post_type' !== $post['post_type'] ) {
        return $post;
    }

    $date = get_post_field( 'post_date', $post['ID'], 'raw' );
    $post['post_date'] = $date;
    $post['post_date_gmt'] = get_gmt_from_date( $date );

    return $post;
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', function() {
    # Make sure above callback is only triggered once
    remove_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', '\WPSE\save' );
} );
```

IIRC your main problem with above code is, that the `private_to_published` filter was deprecated, so there is nothing specific enough **aside from a post type status filter**. Try the following plugin and see if it works (if your post type really is named `mycpt`):

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: (WPSE) Test post type status actions */
add_action( 'private_mycpt', function( $ID, \WP_Post $post ) {
    var_dump( current_filter() );
    exit;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: now I see what you were talking about.  But I don't think your code will **make sure** that the code hooked into `wp_insert_post_data` is only executed once because there any number of hooks fired _after_ the post is updated which _could_ trigger another call to `wp_insert_post()`, and hence, another firing of `wp_insert_post_data` and you couldn't possibly enumerate them _all_ (to hook into them and remove the func hooked to `wp_insert_post_data`).

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron The code gets removed as soon as there is a transition. With the arguments (that I have taken from your answer), we can make quite sure that the modifications the callback triggers are limited to very few cases. Anyway, you are not completely off with your comment: While the callback gets removed and not added more than once, the _case_ in which it gets removed probably is not the right one. It might trigger in some other cases as well. And the callback gets removed in other cases as well.

Comment: This code won't work. The code will always return early. The line `if ( ! in_array( $post['post_status'], [ 'private', 'pending', ] ) )` will always return true when clicking "Publish" because `$post['post_status']` refers to the new post_status and not the previous post_status. Also the other code snippet from Paul has the same issue. He calls `original_post_status` which doesn't exist in Wordpress. His code seems to work but only because `original_post_status` doesn't exist and thus returns false. None of the answers in this entire thread are correct and no one cared to double check.

Comment: @KevinM This answer is 5 years old. I am very sure it worked back then just fine. If you found out that something does not work and know how to fix it, then please file an [edit] and contribute your knowledge. This is how this site works: Everyone has [edit] rights and chooses to contribute. And so should you. Good luck and thanks for contributing in advance!